# If $Z_n$ converges to standard normal in distribution, what does $Z_n^2$ converge to?

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, chi-squared-distribution

Suppose $Z_n$ is a sequence of random variables that converge to standard normal in distribution. I saw the claim that $Z_n^2$ converge to chi-square random variable in distribution. But why is that true? How do you prove this?

The only way that I know we can end up with something converges to chi square in distribution is second order delta method, but that doesn't seems to be relevant here.

Comment: [The continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows that the fact that if $Z_n\to Z$ in distribution, and $h$ is a continuous function, then $h(Z_n)\to h(Z)$ in distribution (a hint for the proof of this fact is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915776/continuous-function-keeps-the-convergence-in-distribution).